ValueError: Array element cannot be set with a sequence. Array shape is inhomogeneous after 2 dimensions: (810, 2) + inhomogeneous part
Error occured in the line no 22: 'training = np.array(training)'
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw-1.4')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import random
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
words=[]
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_words = ['?', '!']
data_file = open('/content/drive/MyDrive/DataColab/intents.json').read()
intents = json.loads(data_file)
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        # take each word and tokenize it
        w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(w)
        # adding documents
        documents.append((w, intent['tag']))
        # adding classes to our class list
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])
words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in ignore_words]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))
classes = sorted(list(set(classes)))
#print (len(documents), "documents")
#print (len(classes), "classes", classes)
#print (len(words), "unique lemmatized words", words)
pickle.dump(words,open('words.pkl','wb'))
pickle.dump(classes,open('classes.pkl','wb'))
# initializing training data
training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)
for doc in documents:
    # initializing bag of words
    bag = []
    # list of tokenized words for the pattern
    pattern_words = doc[0]
    # lemmatize each word - create base word, in attempt to represent related words
    pattern_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]
    # create our bag of words array with 1, if word match found in current pattern
    for w in words:
        bag.append(1) if w in pattern_words else bag.append(0)
    # output is a '0' for each tag and '1' for current tag (for each pattern)
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])
# shuffle our features and turn into np.array
random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)
# create train and test lists. X - patterns, Y - intents
train_x = list(training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])
print("Training data created")
# Create model - 3 layers. First layer 128 neurons, second layer 64 neurons and 3rd output layer contains number of neurons
# equal to number of intents to predict output intent with softmax
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0])))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
# Compile model. Stochastic gradient descent with Nesterov accelerated gradient gives good results for this model
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
#fitting and saving the model
hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('chatbot_model.h5', hist)
print("model created")

Traceback:
`ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1a891a7a8859> in <cell line: 22>()
     20 # shuffle our features and turn into np.array
     21 random.shuffle(training)
---> 22 training = np.array(training)
     23 # create train and test lists. X - patterns, Y - intents
     24 train_x = list(training[:,0])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (810, 2) + inhomogeneous part.

In a YouTube video from a year ago, this NumPy function worked perfectly, but it now throws an error.
I tried updating the 'NumPy' module but it's incompatible with the new version of 'Keras'.
Can someone help me understand how to use the 'NumPy' function or fix this error?`

Your training list does not contain lists or arrays of a consistent size.  This error message is the current numpy version's way of complaining about 'ragged' data.

Did you check the commenys of that video (or any linked website)?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
